# Javascript: async vs async="async"

Tags: javascript, jquery

async is a good way to eliminate render-blocking resources, so I am trying to implement that in one of my projects. However, I see people declaring that in different ways:

```
<script src="demo_async.js" async></script>
```

and

```
<script src="demo_async.js" async="async"></script>
```

Does it matter which way it is being declared? Especially in terms of browser compatibility...

Comment: @herecticMonkey No It does not. But Thanks!

Comment: The accepted answer to that question states "setting async=true, async=false or async=anything all mean the same thing.", which is exactly what the accepted answer to this question states. Don't see how that *doesn't* answer your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's a boolean attribute so it doesn't matter if you give it a value or not.

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-async):

> This is a boolean attribute: the presence of a boolean attribute on an
>   element represents the true value, and the absence of the attribute
>   represents the false value.